# How to Set Screen Resolution At run time in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, splash-screen

i have a problem guys i made a wpf applications its running well but when i run the  application on different screen resolution, then the controls(i.e. the size) added in the xbap page changes. So i want to get  the current screen resolution and make the size of controls unchangable.Can anyone help me out.

thanks in advance Radhe Govind

```
<Window x:Class="MedSelectNew.ImageSelection"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2007/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"  
 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MedSelectNew"   

Title="ImageSelection" WindowState="Maximized"  Loaded="Window_Loaded" ShowInTaskbar="False" WindowStyle="None" Background="Black" Width="{x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}" Height="{x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}" KeyDown="Window_KeyDown">
```

Comment: Doesn't specifying explicit sizes for each control achieve that ? (I'd recommend against this.. apps are supposed to render differently in different resolutions. e.g. I'd not like an app rendering huge buttons meant for 800v600 when I am on a 1920v1080 resolution display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the DPI-adjusted primary screen resolution from these properties:

```
SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenHeight
SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenWidth
```

It is not clear to me why you would want this, however.  If you want your controls to be smaller when your window is smaller, just use WPF's layout capabilities along with ViewBox.  If not, just give all your controls the same size.  Either way I don't see how the current screen resolution comes into the picture.